# Linq: Considering table as not nothinh in a if statement even if table is empty

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, if-statement

I'm doing a simple linq request like this:

```
    Dim r = (From p In db.Product _
             Where p.Product_ID = ProductID _                   
             Select p)

    If (r IsNot Nothing) Then
          'doing stuff here
    End If
```

My problem is eventhought the request return an empty table (I tried with a count too) it consider the table as not empty and execute the code inside the "if"...

Any idea where is that coming from?

Comment: 0 accepted answers out of 9 eligible question? Why? Were you aware of how accepting answers work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: try forcing query evaluation by `.ToList()` execution: `Dim r = (From ... Select p).ToList()`

Comment: I tried that too, it's doing the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq will always return something from this. Even if it is an empty IEnumerable(Of T). Try switching the If to `If r.Any() Then` and see if that gives you the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that code inside if statement be executed only if the query returned some values you should use something like that:

```
If (r IsNot Nothing AndAlso r.Any()) Then
          'doing stuff here
End If
```

Comment: @blop - maybe because it actually *is* empty?

Comment: Why still check `IsNot Nothing`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to execute the query. I've been away from VB sometime so excuse the syntax errors ;)

```
Dim r = (From p In db.Product _
         Where p.Product_ID = ProductID _                   
         Select New(){productid = p.Product_ID}).ToList()

If (r.Count() > 0) Then
      'doing stuff here
End If
```

Comment: I'm sorry I (falsely) concluded the product id was a primary key. I'll update my answer